# Loaded the data to Hive with wrong delimiter

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have 10TB of data  in Local, I have loaded the data using single delimiter (~), but the some fields in the data has that delimiter in their words, so the data is appended to next column, How Can I alter that table to make it correct ?

Comment: You can fix the datafile and use pipe as delimiter. Then reload it again.

Comment: If you didn't load it as plain text, you can't fix the Hive table after you've loaded the wrong delimiter. You will need to reimport it correctly.